# Is it always good to use Vec3f / Vec4f class defined by yourself?

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

A question about coding style:
When you're going to reconstruct a virtural scene containing plenty of objects (Using JOGL), is it always good to define a Vec3f class and face class representing the vertices, normals, and faces rather than to directly use float[] type? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people go step further and create a Vertex POD object of type:

```
struct Vertex{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec2 texture;
}
```

Then the stride is simply `sizeof(Vertex)`, and the offsets can be extracted using a `offsetof` macro. This leads to a more robust setup when passing the data.